# SQL count occurrence of value by distinct id

Tags: sql

Given following table **A**

```
FlightID| Roles
1       | Pilot
1       | Steward
1       | Steward
2       | Pilot
2       | Co-Pilot
```

How can I determine the number of stewards on each distinct flight? The output should be like this:

```
FlightID| Count
1       | 2
2       | 0
```

First I tried:

```
select FlightID, count(Role) from A group by FlightID
```

but this gives me the total number of roles per flight. Then I tried:

```
select FlightID, count(Role) from A where Role="Steward" group by FlightID
```

this is partially right since it gives me the number of stewards per flight, but it does not take into account 0 stewards. How can I also include 0 stewards into the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your table really not have a primary key on it?  If it does, this is a fairly easy `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a1.FlightId, COUNT(a2.FlightId) 
FROM A a1 LEFT JOIN A a2 ON a1.id = a2.id
AND a2.Roles = 'Steward'
GROUP BY a1.FlightId;
```

http://ideone.com/BySBSx

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN was the key.

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
select FlightID
,sum(case when Role = 'Steward' then 1 else 0 end) 
--or count(case when Role = 'Steward' then 1 end)
from A 
group by FlightID
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you see a way without using "case when .. then .. else .. end"?